# Suggestions for tooltip link plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I need a Tooltip plugin very much similar to as Facebook uses for showing profile & pages in tooltips.

I tried out a few. I was happy with this plugin which uses YQL to retrieve info for the links.

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/jquery-anchorcloud-expanding-link_09.html

I would like to have a plugin very much similar to this one. Since there are a few functionality issues with that one